# Long Connect on TCP Socket

Tags: sockets, tcp

Can you please assist. I am integrating with a device that requires a long connect option according to the manufacturer. Do you have any idea how this can be done?

This is the code I have so far which works in most cases:

```
public AsynchronousSocketListener(IPEndPoint endPoint, ILog log)
{
    _EndPoint = endPoint;
    _log = log;
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Started: {0}:{1}", endPoint.Address, endPoint.Port));
}

public void StartListening()
{
    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);

    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
    try
    {

        socket.Bind(_EndPoint);
        socket.Listen(100000);
        Console.WriteLine("Listen");

        while (true)
        {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            socket.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    socket);

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Error:{0}", ex.Message));
    }
}


public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    allDone.Set();

    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    // Create the state object.
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}

public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
        // more data.
        content = state.sb.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("RECEIVED: {0}", content));
        if (content.IndexOf("\u0001") > -1)
        {
            string imei = string.Empty;
            foreach (string response in ResponseHandler.GetRequestResponse(content, out imei))
            {
                Send(handler, response, imei);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("RESPONSE: {0}", response));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Not all data received. Get more.
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }
}

private void Send(Socket handler, String data, string imei)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    //Terminator
    byte[] terminator = new byte[3] { 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };
    //Create new array with added 3 spaces for terminator
    byte[] terminalResponse = new byte[byteData.Length + 3];
    //Copy command byte array to new array
    byteData.CopyTo(terminalResponse, 0);
    //Copy terminator byte array to new array
    terminator.CopyTo(terminalResponse, terminalResponse.Length - 3);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    handler.BeginSend(terminalResponse, 0, terminalResponse.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);

        //handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        //handler.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it "works in most cases", then what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: What's a "long connect" option?

Comment: For certain calls I just don't receive the data and the manufacturer help informed me I am not applying a long connect option. Stumped. I thought maybe it is some option on the SocketOptions but I am pretty new to the TCP server code writing thing :)

Comment: You should address your question to the manufacturer. I'm not aware of a 'long connection' option in TCP, but then I've only been using it for nearly 30 years. At present the strong presumption has to be that the manufacturer doesn't know what he's talking about.

Comment: Probably a receive bug although I don't see one. Note, that you have based your code on a bad MSDN sample. That makes your life quite hard. If you use synchronous socket IO the code becomes vastly simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback guys

Comment: That sample code isn't that bad by the way, @AntonSwanevelder. For a small and simple TCP application, if you wrote async sockets yourself, it wouldn't end up looking that much different. Also, maybe by 'long connect' they meant 'try several times' if it doesn't work at first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys, I failed to respond on this, but found that the SocketOptionName.KeepAlive seemed to have solved the issue:

```
// Create a TCP/IP socket.
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
```

And making sure the socket is not closed at the end.

Comment: If this is what the manufacturer meant he should have said so, and you should complain to him that he didn't.

Comment: Thanks for your help EJP, unfortunately there is a bit of a communication with Mandarin.

Answer (score -1):

This maybe help someone, or else if you can see how to improve this please let me know. But here is the version I am currently using:

```
public async Task StartListening()
{
    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);

    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
    try
    {
        socket.Bind(_EndPoint);
        socket.Listen(100000);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Socket connected to {0}", _EndPoint.Address));

        while (true)
        {
            // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.  
            Socket handler = socket.Accept();
            data = null;

            // An incoming connection needs to be processed.  
            while (true)
            {
                bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                if (data.IndexOf("\u0001") > -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

           Console.WriteLine(String.Format("RECEIVED: {0}", data));

            // Echo the data back to the client.  
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            handler.Send(msg);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Error:{0}", ex.Message));
    }
}
```